# context manager exit called before code in body

Tags: python, contextmanager

I've been playing around with making my own context managers in Python.  I'm seeing some strange behavior most likely due to my implementation.

I see the `__exit__` code called before a statement in the 'with' context.  For example, here is the code snippet:

```
with ProgressBar(10) as p:
  p.update(1)
```

and it's exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'update'
```

I put debug in all the `__enter__`, `__exit__`, and update methods of my context manager.  It looks like `__exit__` is called before update().  This makes no sense so I must be missing something simple.

Here is my simple context manager class:

```
class ProgressBar(object):
    """Progress bar that normalizes progress to [0 - 100] scale"""

    def __init__(self, max_value):
        """Create progress bar with max_value"""

        self._current_value = 0.0
        self._completed_value = 100.0
        self._max_value = float(max_value)
        print 'init', max_value

    def __enter__(self):
        """Start of context manager, 'with' statement"""

        print 'enter'
        self._current_value = 0.0

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        """Start of context manager, 'with' statement"""

        print 'exit'
        self._current_value = self._completed_value

        # Not handling any exceptions, so they'll be raised automatically
        # To ignore exceptions return True or inspect arguments to handle

        return False

    def update(self, value):
        """Update progress value"""

        print 'update'
        if value >= self._max_value:
            self._current_value = 100
        else:
            self._current_value = (value / self._max_value) * self._completed_value

        print '\r%s' % (self._current_value),
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the documentation:

> `object.__enter__(self)`
>
> Enter the runtime context related to this object.  The `with` statement
>   will bind this method’s return value to the target(s)  specified in
>   the `as` clause of the statement, if any.

You're not returning anything from `__enter__` (and thus you're returning None, as always).  If you `return self`, you'll get

```
init 10
enter
update
10.0 exit
```

Answer (score 2):

The `with` statement binds the *return value* of a context manager [`__enter__` method](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__enter__) to the variable. In your case that means `p` is bound to `None` (your `__enter__` doesn't have a return statement at all, so `None` is the default), an `AttributeError` is raised and the `__exit__` method is called.

The solution is to return `self` from the `__enter__` method:

```
def __enter__(self):
    """Start of context manager, 'with' statement"""

    print 'enter'
    self._current_value = 0.0
    return self
```

Comment: ah ha!  Thanks.  I knew it was something simple.